# Sort Unique column in Unix

Tags: sorting, unix, uniq

I have been looking for an answer for a good amount of time but it seems that it hasn't been answered yet. I do apologize if this question has already been answered.

So i am trying to sort the number of appearances from each ID from High to Low.

From the following command: `sort -k1,1 File.txt | uniq -c`
I get this result :

```
1 21423 
3 21447
5 21448
3 21513
1 21584 
1 21585
1 21586
```

The result I want:

```
5 21448
3 21447
3 21513
1 21423 
1 21584 
1 21585
1 21586
```

It does sort the second column even though I typed `-k1,1`
I have tried different parameters and options such as `-n`. Any leads would help me a lot. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to sort the output of `uniq -c`:

```
... | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

When you want to sort lines by the count,
it doesn't matter how the items were sorted before calling `uniq -c`,
because the counts will only be known after the call to `uniq -c`.

Comment: Yea that crossed my mind. It seems to work now, thanks for your time!